# Complementary DNA sequence

Tags: for-loop, python-3.x, sequence

I'm having a problem writing this loop; it seems to stop after the second sequence.

I want to return the complementary DNA sequence to the given DNA sequence.

E.g. ('AGATTC') -> ('TCTAAG'), where A:T and C:G

```
def get_complementary_sequence(dna):
    """(str) -> str

> Return the DNA sequence that is complementary to the given DNA sequence

    >>> get_complementary_sequence('AT')
    ('TA')
    >>> get_complementary_sequence('AGATTC')
    ('TCTAAG')

    """

    x = 0
    complementary_sequence = ''

    for char in dna:
            complementary_sequence = (get_complement(dna))

    return complementary_sequence + (dna[x:x+1])
```

Can anyone spot why the loop does not continue?

Comment: What does `get_complement` do?

Comment: get_complement produces the complementry base pair eg. 'A':'T'

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example how I would do it - only several lines of code really:

```
from string import maketrans

DNA="CCAGCTTATCGGGGTACCTAAATACAGAGATAT" #example DNA fragment

def complement(sequence):
  reverse = sequence[::-1]
  return reverse.translate(maketrans('ATCG','TAGC'))

print complement(DNA)
```

Answer (score 2):

You call `get_complement` on all of `dna` instead of each `char`. This will simply call the came function with the same parameters len(dna) times. There's no reason to loop through the `char`s if you never use them. If `get_complement()` can take a char, I would recommend:

```
for char in dna:
    complementary_sequence += get_complement(char)
```

The implementation of get_complement would take a single character and return its complement.

Also, you're returning `complementary_sequence + (dna[x:x+1])`. If you want the function to conform to the behavior that you've documented, the `+ (dna[x:x+1])` will add an extra (wrong) character from the beginning off the `dna` string. All you need to return is `complementary_sequence`! Thanks to @Kevin for noticing.

What you're doing:

```
>>> dna = "1234"
>>> for char in dna:
...     print dna
... 
1234
1234
1234
1234
```

what I think is closer to what you want to be doing:

```
>>> for char in dna:
...     print char
... 
1
2
3
4
```

Putting it all together:

```
# you could also use a list comprehension, with a join() call, but
# this is closer to your original implementation.
def get_complementary_sequence(seq):
    complement = ''
    for char in seq:
        complement += get_complement(char)
    return complement

def get_complement(base):
    complements = {'A':'T', 'T':'A', 'C':'G', 'G':'C'}
    return complements[base]

>>> get_complementary_sequence('AT')
'TA'
>>> get_complementary_sequence('AGATTC')
'TCTAAG'
```

Comment: @user2773611 this does print the complementary string

Comment: just tried the above code, it only produced: get_complementary_sequence('AGATTC') returns 'T'

Comment: @user2773611 I think you were misunderstanding my explanation. I've edited to give you a full, working version. Maybe I understood what get_complement was supposed to do wrongly.

Comment: your get_complement works great, its just when i run get_complementary_sequence('AGATTC') i get ('T')

Comment: @user2773611 are you using exactly the one I implemented? It works, as you can see from the test cases. Are you sure that the loop is correctly indented? If it isn't, it would potentially run once, and you would see that behavior.

Comment: thanks for your help i was wrong on my side. works good, thanks

Answer (score 2):

### What's wrong?

You're calling:

```
complementary_sequence = (get_complement(dna))
```

...*n* times where *n* is the length of the string. This leaves you with whatever the return value of `get_complement(dna)` is in `complementary_sequence`. Presumably just one letter.

You then return this one letter (`complementary_sequence`) followed by the substring `dna[0:1]` (*i.e.* the first letter in `dna`), because `x` is *always* `0`.

This would be why you always get two characters returned.

### How to fix it?

Assuming you have a function like:

```
def get_complement(d):
    return {'T': 'A', 'A': 'T', 'C': 'G', 'G': 'C'}.get(d, d)
```

...you could fix your function by simply using [`str.join()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and a [*list comprehension*](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
def get_complementary_sequence(dna):
    """(str) -> str

> Return the DNA sequence that is complementary to the given DNA sequence

    >>> get_complementary_sequence('AT')
    ('TA')
    >>> get_complementary_sequence('AGATTC')
    ('TCTAAG')

    """

    return ''.join([get_complement(c) for c in dna])
```